# Wave Simulation with Python

Tags: python, numpy, simulation, physics, wave

I want to simulate a propagating wave with absorption and reflection on some bodies in three dimensional space. I want to do it with python. Should I use numpy? Are there some special libraries I should use?

How can I simulate the wave? Can I use the wave equation? But what if I have a reflection?
Is there a better method? Should I do it with vectors? But when the ray diverge the intensity gets lower. Difficult.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pick an algorithm first, then ask about implementation in Python.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do any computationally intensive numerical simulation in Python, you should *definitely* use NumPy.

The most general algorithm to simulate an electromagnetic wave in arbitrarily-shaped materials is the [finite-difference time domain method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FDTD) (FDTD). It solves the wave equation, one time-step at a time, on a 3-D lattice. It is quite complicated to program yourself, though, and you are probably better off using a dedicated package such as [Meep](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Meep).

There are books on how to write your own FDTD simulations: [here's one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Numerical-Electromagnetics-Umran-S-Inan/dp/052119069X), [here's](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/~dennis/ECE538-files/Intro%28FDTD%29.doc) a document with some code for 1-D FDTD and explanations on more than 1 dimension, and Googling "[writing FDTD](http://www.google.nl/search?q=writing+FDTD)" will find you more of the same.

You could also approach the problem by assuming all your waves are plane waves, then you could use vectors and the [Fresnel equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations). Or if you want to model Gaussian beams being transmitted and reflected from flat or curved surfaces, you could use the ABCD matrix formalism (also known as [ray transfer matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_transfer_matrix_analysis)). This takes into account the divergence of beams.

Comment: Hi ptomato, difficult stuff but I think I will read about FDTD at first. Thank you!

Comment: It seems to difficult to run Meep on Windows. :(

Comment: @kame - I know. That's very unfortunate. However, it's the only open source solution I'm aware of - otherwise you can either write your own (see edit to the answer) or use an expensive commercial program (RSoft, Lumerical, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are solving 3D custom PDEs, I would recommend at least a look at [FiPy](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/).  It'll save you the trouble of building a lot of your matrix conditioners and solvers from scratch.  It uses numpy and/or trilinos.  Here are some [examples](http://www.matforge.org/fipy/wiki/FiPyExamples).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use my project [GarlicSim](http://garlicsim.org) as the framework in which you build the simulation. You will still need to write your algorithm yourself, probably in Numpy, but GarlicSim may save you a bunch of boilerplate and allow you to explore your simulation results in a flexible way, similar to version control systems.

Answer (score -5):

Don't use Python. I've tried using it for computationally expensive things and it just wasn't made for that.

If you *need* to simulate a wave in a Python program, write the necessary code in C/C++ and export it to Python.
Here's a link to the C API: http://docs.python.org/c-api/
Be warned, it isn't the easiest API in the world :)

Comment: NumPy is perfectly suitable for computationally expensive things.

Comment: Okay, I think I don't have to do it necessarily in python :/

Comment: -1 because Python has widely used scientific libraries like numpy/scipy. Have also a look at other ways of optimizing python code like cython, psyco. Finally, use efficient algorithms ;)

Comment: @Andrea Spadaccini and do not forget Weave! :-D (it is inside scipy though, but worth to mention explicitly)

Comment: Well, for PDE's there will simply remain an order of magnitude difference between NumPy and C/Fortran and alike. No-one showed an counterexample yet, but if you have one, feel free to show it to me.