# Sound Waves Simiulation in 3D Environment

Tags: simulation, physics

Hi: I want to do a sound waves simulation that include wave propagation, absorbing and reflection in 3D space.

I do some searches and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956331/wave-simulation-with-python) in stackoverflow but it talk about electromagnetic waves not sound waves.

I know i can reimplement the **FDTD** method for sound waves but how about the sources and does it act like the electromagnetic waves ? Is there any resources to start with ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try on the [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can give you some inputs...
As far as i know, in EM simulations obstacles (and thus terrain) are not considered at all. With sound you have to consider reflection, diffraction, etc

there are different standards to calculate the noise originated from different sources (I'll list the europe ones, the one i know of):

- traffic, NMPB (NMPB-Routes-96) is THE standard. All the noise calculations have to be done with that one (at least in my country). Results aren't very good. A "new" algorithm is SonRoad (i think it uses inverse ray-tracing)... from my tests it works great.
- trains: Schall03
- industries, ISO 9613
- a list of all the used models in CadnaA (a professional software) so you can google them all: http://www.datakustik.com/en/products/cadnaa/modeling-and-calculation/calculation-standards/

another pro software is SoundPlan, somewhere on the web there is a free "SoundPlan-ReferenceManual.pdf" 800-pages with the mathematical description of the implemented algorithms... i haven't had any luck with google today tough

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is use the SoundPlan software. Multiple sound propagation methods such as ISO9613-2, CONCAWE and Nord2000 are implemented. It has basic 3D visualization with sound pressure level contours.